# pgfplots Error when trying to read a copy of a .csv file that works if not renamed

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, csv

I'm writing my thesis and this is the first time, I've ever encountered this kind of problem. So, I'm constantly working with csv files, with no problem. Yesterday, this started to happen:

This block of code works:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        y label style={at={(0.05,0.5)}},
        ylabel = Force (kN),
        xlabel = Deflection (mm),
        legend style={at={(0.5,-0.2)},anchor=north},
        legend columns=3,%transpose legend,
        legend cell align={left},
    ]
        \addplot[solid, thick] table[x=x,y=TA1, col sep=comma,smooth,mark=none] {pics/01/HAK.csv};
        \addlegendentry{$d_r = 1.5\%$};
        \addplot[thick, dashed] table[x=x,y=TA2, col sep=comma,smooth,mark=none] {pics/01/HAK.csv};
        \addlegendentry{$d_r = 2.5\%$};
        \addplot[thick, dashdotted] table[x=x,y=TA3, col sep=comma,smooth,mark=none] {pics/01/HAK.csv};
        \addlegendentry{$d_r = 1.0\%$};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

If I copy the "HAK.csv" file (same directory, same everything), and just rename it into anything, e.g. "bbbb.csv"

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        y label style={at={(0.05,0.5)}},
        ylabel=Force (kN),
        xlabel=Deflection (mm),
        legend style={at={(0.5,-0.2)},anchor=north},
        legend columns=3,%transpose legend,
        legend cell align={left},
    ]
        \addplot[solid, thick] table[x=x,y=TA1, col sep=comma,smooth,mark=none] {pics/01/bbbb.csv};
        \addlegendentry{$d_r = 1.5\%$};
        \addplot[thick, dashed] table[x=x,y=TA2, col sep=comma,smooth,mark=none] {pics/01/HAK.csv};
        \addlegendentry{$d_r = 2.5\%$};
        \addplot[thick, dashdotted] table[x=x,y=TA3, col sep=comma,smooth,mark=none] {pics/01/HAK.csv};
        \addlegendentry{$d_r = 1.0\%$};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I get an error:

! Package pgfplots Error: Could not read table file 'pics/01/bbbb.csv' in 'sear
ch path=.'. In case you intended to provide inline data: maybe TeX screwed up y
our end-of-lines? Try `row sep=crcr' and terminate your lines with` \' (refer
to the pgfplotstable manual for details).

I'm stuck and can't get an idea how to handel this, as it works until it is renamed.

Comment: Hi Barefoot_fiki, welcome to TeX.SE! Can you at least provide the csv-files, preferably through `filecontents` or even better a complete MWE? Otherwise it is hard for others to follow up your issue.

Comment: Which operating system do you use, Windows, Mac, Linux? Maybe the problem is that you accidentally mixed up lower and upper case, for example in the extension, or maybe when renaming the extension is added twice (`bbbb.csv.csv`) and your file manager does not show that?

Comment: [tag:Marijn] I'm using WIN10. I've checked the double extension, and copied the renamed name. No luck

Comment: This is very unlikely to happen. Besides the stuff already mentioned you could test: 1. Delete all auxiliary files and TeX again. 2. Copy the above code to a new file as well as the preamble from your current document and TeX that file. Does one of them work?